# Run ASP.NET MVC Preview 3 (or 4 or 5) and MVC Beta simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just recently installed the MVC beta.
However, I assumed because the versioning numbers have changed and because it now uses the GAC instead of the bin folder that it wouldn't break existing applications.

However, it has.

What steps do I need to follow to ensure my existing preview 3 applications use a bin copy of the .dlls and are not broken by the installation of the beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC beta is also bin-deployable, Move the following DLL's from GAC to the bin folder of your app

```
* System.Web.Mvc
* System.Web.Routing
* System.Web.Abstractions
```

[Check this article for more information](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I was aware it was bin-deployable, just didn't realise bin deployment and GAC were exclusive.

Comment: See Brad Wilson's post too for more info. The link you posted had a useful comment.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to force uninstall (gacutil /u /f System.Web.Mvc) the Beta DLL from the GAC, and then use bin deployment for all versions (including the beta).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware it was bin-deployable, just didn't realise bin deployment and GAC were exclusive.  Interestingly, phil haack mentions that gacutil wasn't suitable in the link rajlogs posted.

Comment: Unless /f overrides that problem :-)

Comment: You can use a newer version from bin, but not an older one, and all the pre-beta versions were 0.0 whereas the beta is 1.0, so the presence of 1.0 in the GAC invalidates the 0.0 in bin.

Comment: Thanks - I wish I could spend some rep or something to vote this as accepted answer too because that little comment answered my question - just feel bad taking the accepted answer from a low rep :-)

Comment: Hmm gacutil doesn't work for the reasons outlined in the link rajlogs posted, so I'll have to uninstall MVC, but then I'll lose templates and stuff won't I?

Comment: http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2008/11/working-on-aspnet-mvc-beta-and-preview.html is helpful.